# AWS DMS oracle full load failed

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, dms

I am running an RDS oracle 12 TO RDS Oracle 12. But my task fails with the below error.Could not understand what is the issue.

> Last Error Failed to connect to database. Task error notification
> received from subtask 2, thread 1 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2822]
> [1020414] Failed executing create PK statement: ALTER TABLE
> "1234"."MST" ADD CONSTRAINT "SYS_C0011324" PRIMARY KEY ( "SEC",
> "TARIFF" ); ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint ;
> Handling new table '1234'.'MST' failed; Endpoint is disconnected;
> Error executing data handler; Stream component failed at subtask 2,
> component st_2_GP7OZL3BRFLFYLJHGB3UF4TNMYELVSRAJMZIA; Stream component
> 'st_2_GP7OZL3BRFLFYLJH3UF4TNMYELVSRCXAJMZIA' terminated
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2829] [1020414] Stop Reason
> RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
>
> Cause: The specified constraint name has to be unique.
>
> Action: Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

Your constraint name "SYS_C0011324" is system-generated, and appears to overlap with a different system-generated constraint name in the target database. You will need to change the constraint name in one database or the other to avoid the conflict, then try your load again.

Comment: actually i am trying a fresh load my target DB is completely empty

Comment: It's a system generated name that has to be unique. Something is already using it, perhaps in the data dictionary. Rename it in your source and try again.